# ¿Cómo programo el AddHandler para una matriz de controles con C#?

Tags: c#

A continuación os voy a reproducir el código para una matriz de controles TextBox que estoy haciendo en C#. No necesito que nadie me explique la lógica del AddHandler, sólo necesito saber cómo tendría que escribir el código para que funcione correctamente, y a partir de ahí ya me arreglo yo para cuando necesite hacer una matriz de controles del tipo que sea.

Hay un apartado en el que veis que comento que ahí es donde quiero introducir los AddHandlers. En Visual Basic.Net escribiría lo siguiente:

```
        AddHandler MatrizDeTextBoxes(Contador).Enter, AddressOf AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto
        AddHandler MatrizDeTextBoxes(Contador).Click, AddressOf AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto
        AddHandler MatrizDeTextBoxes(Contador).Leave, AddressOf AlSalirDeUnCuadroDeTexto
```

Me gustaría que alguien me dijera cómo escribir lo equivalente a estas tres líneas que acabo de reproducir, pero en C#.

A continuación, reproduzco el código completo que tengo:

```
    private const int Lado = 40, DistanciaIzquierda = 200, DistanciaArriba = 150, DistanciaMinima = 15, DistanciaMaxima = 20;
    private TextBox[] MatrizDeTextBoxes = new TextBox[81];

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrearLaMatrizDeControles();
    }

    private void CrearLaMatrizDeControles()
    {
        int XAux, YAux;
        int Contador;

        for (Contador = 0; Contador <= 80; Contador++)
        {
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador] = new TextBox();
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].MaxLength = 1;
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].BackColor = Color.White;
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size = new Size(MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height,MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height);
            XAux = DistanciaIzquierda + (Contador % 9) * (MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Width + DistanciaMinima);
            YAux = DistanciaArriba + (Contador / 9) * (MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height + DistanciaMinima) + (Contador / 27) * (DistanciaMaxima - DistanciaMinima);
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Location = new Point(XAux, YAux);
            MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Name = Convert.ToString(Contador);
            this.Controls.Add(MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador]);

        }
```

// Aquí quiero introducir los AddHandlers

```
            XAux = 2 * DistanciaIzquierda + 9 * MatrizDeTextBoxes[0].Width + 6 * DistanciaMinima + 2 * DistanciaMaxima;
            YAux = 2 * DistanciaArriba + 9 * MatrizDeTextBoxes[0].Height + 6 * DistanciaMinima + 3 * DistanciaMaxima + button1.Size.Height;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(XAux, YAux);
            XAux = this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - button1.Size.Width / 2;
            YAux = this.ClientSize.Height - DistanciaArriba - button1.Size.Height;
            button1.Location = new Point(XAux, YAux);

    }

    private void AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto(TextBox sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ControlEnlazado = sender;
        ControlEnlazado.SelectAll();
    }
    private void AlSalirDeUnCuadroDeTexto(TextBox sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ControlEnlazado = sender;
        if (ControlEnlazado.Text == " ") ControlEnlazado.Text = "";
        if(ControlEnlazado.Text!="" && Convert.ToChar(ControlEnlazado.Text) <'1' && Convert.ToChar(ControlEnlazado.Text)>'9')
        {
            AdvertimosAlUsuario("Tienes que introducir un dígito distinto de 0 o dejar el cuadro vacío", "Contenido de cuadrícula inválido");
            ControlEnlazado.Focus();
        }

    }
    private void AdvertimosAlUsuario(string CadenaDeTexto,string CadenaDeTitulo)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(CadenaDeTexto, CadenaDeTitulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Carlos podrias decirme si la respuesta te resulto util, gracias

Comment: Sí, me ha sido de una grandísima ayuda. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Carlos si la respuesta te resulto util no olvides marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Comment: @Japv vale, ¿cómo lo hago?

Comment: Justo al lado de mi respuesta hay dos triangulitos(flechas) para votar la respuesta, el triangulo hacia arriba es un voto positivo y hacia abajo un voto negativo, en esa zona por dd estan los triangulitos hay un checkMark, sobre ese checkmark es dd tienes que dar clic y ya habras aceptado mi respuesta, tu todavia no puedes dar votos pq no tienes reputacion, pero si puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: @Japv me parece que ya lo he hecho, avísame si lo he hecho mal para corregirlo.

Comment: Si Carlos, todo ok, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Contador = 0; Contador <= 80; Contador++)
{
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador] = new TextBox();
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].MaxLength = 1;
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].BackColor = Color.White;
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size = new Size(MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height,MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height);
   XAux = DistanciaIzquierda + (Contador % 9) * (MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Width + DistanciaMinima);
   YAux = DistanciaArriba + (Contador / 9) * (MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Size.Height + DistanciaMinima) + (Contador / 27) * (DistanciaMaxima - DistanciaMinima);
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Location = new Point(XAux, YAux);
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Name = Convert.ToString(Contador);
   
   //Aquí se añaden los manejadores de eventos
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Enter += new EventHandler(AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto); 
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Click += new EventHandler(AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto);      
   MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Leave += new EventHandler(AlSalirDeUnCuadroDeTexto);

   this.Controls.Add(MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador]);
}
```

En el mismo **ciclo for** que creas los **TextBoxes** debes poner este código:

```
MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Enter += new EventHandler(AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto); 
MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Click += new EventHandler(AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto);      
MatrizDeTextBoxes[Contador].Leave += new EventHandler(AlSalirDeUnCuadroDeTexto);
```

De esta forma estás creando diferentes **manejadores de evento** para cada **TextBox**, recuerda que el método que añadas al **manejador de eventos**, debe cumplir con reglas que debes respetar, es decir cada manejador de eventos acepta un método con determinada firma, por ejemplo, el **evento Enter**, acepta un método cuya firma sea un **método void** y que acepte dos parámetros uno de tipo **object** y otro de tipo **EventArgs**.

Debes cambiar la estructura de tus métodos ya que no tienen la firma que acepta el **manejador de evento EventHandler**, por lo que quedarían de esta forma:

```
private void AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox ControlEnlazado = sender as TextBox;
    ControlEnlazado.SelectAll();
}

private void AlSalirDeUnCuadroDeTexto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox ControlEnlazado = sender as TextBox;

    if (ControlEnlazado.Text == " ") 
    {
       ControlEnlazado.Text = "";
    }
    
    if (ControlEnlazado.Text != "" && Convert.ToChar(ControlEnlazado.Text) < '1' && Convert.ToChar(ControlEnlazado.Text) > '9')
    {
        AdvertimosAlUsuario("Tienes que introducir un dígito distinto de 0 o dejar el cuadro vacío", "Contenido de cuadrícula inválido");
        ControlEnlazado.Focus();
    }
}
```

Como ves antes tu **parámetro sender** era de tipo **TextBox** y ahora lo cambiamos a tipo **object**, y dentro de estos metodos usamos la instrucción:

```
TextBox ControlEnlazado = sender as TextBox;
```

De esta forma convertimos a **TextBox** el objeto almacenado en el **parámetro sender**.

Comment: Hola amigo. Lo primero, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, y discúlpame por haber tardado tanto en contestar. He copiado y pegado esas tres líneas de texto que me has puesto, y me da en cada línea el siguiente mensaje de error: "Non-invocable member 'EventHandler' cannot be used like a method". ¿Sabes cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: @CarlosMartínezTrueba revisa lo nuevo que puse, faltaba la palabra new para crear los manejadores de eventos

Comment: Japv lo he probado, y ahora el mensaje de error que se repite 3 veces (es decir, una por cada línea) es el siguiente: "No overload for 'AlEntrarEnElCuadroDeTexto' matches delegate 'EventHandler'".

Comment: @CarlosMartínezTrueba revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: ¡Ahora sí! ¡Funciona! ¡Muchísimas gracias, amigo! En Visual Basic.Net podía cambiar el sender de object a TextBox, pero ya veo que en C# no me deja. ¡Muchísimas gracias, me has sido de gran ayuda!